# Trouble creating a basic clock app for Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm trying to create a simple screensaver for personal use.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to update the clock once it's been displayed. I have a global variable tied to message port that should update the function every x ms, however for whatever reason that's the singular function that remains static. My background changes, the screen fade animation changes, yet no matter where I put the `text=roDatetime` outside of `init()`, it just never updates.

So, I'm hoping someone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or simply not doing at all, so I can get this working already.

Edit (for clarification):

I have a text clock (in a label) on top of a rotating background, and I'm using a m.global.observeField paired with a wait/port to trigger the function to update the time.

However I found that the issue had to do with the order in which I had the functions setup (i.e. the order of the function triggers were causing the issue), and while it's not 100% where I want it, it's working now so at this point it's no longer a coding issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an example of your code that demonstrates the issue. It is hard to suggest solutions without seeing the code you have written so far.

Comment: @totallynotkeanureeves Hii, my answer is helpful to you?.

Comment: Pls, Do not Put the answer in question. It's difficult for new learners. Pls, Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Timer node](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/timer.md). You could do something like this:

in xml:

```
<Timer id="minuteTimer" repeat="true" duration="60"/>
```

and in your brightscript:

```
sub init()
   m.timer = m.top.findNode("minuteTimer")
   m.timer.observeField("fire", "updateMinuteHand")
end sub

sub updateMinuteHand(event as object)
   ' do what you need to here
end sub
```

alternatively, you can create the Timer node in brightscript like this instead of in the xml:

```
m.timer = createObject("roSGNode", "Timer")
m.timer.repeat = true
m.timer.duration = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Which type of clock you perform in Roku So, I Simply here [AnalogClock](https://github.com/chaklasiyanikunj/KeyboardDialogExample/blob/master/clock.zip) example and Digital Clock for simply use Overhang tag like below.

```
<Overhang
      showClock="true"
      translation="[60,170]" 
/>
```

[image]

Using overhang tag. You displayed Right-End Corner Like This image.
Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really what I was looking for, however I figured out what my issue was so it's all good.